# Is Inner join Equivalence relation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join

I have two tables, one having 60 lacs record serving as master data. Another table holds some search criteria. Now I need to make an inner join. I have two choices. Master data inner join condition or condition inner join master data. Which one will prove more efficient ?

In other words, can A join B prove more efficient over B Join A on certain conditions ?

Comment: I guess by "60 lacs" you mean 60 lakhs = 60 * 100.000, i.e. 6 million records do you?

Comment: Yup, being from Indian origin, we hardly use term million :)

Comment: Wow.  So that what "lacs" (lakhs) is!  I have been totally curious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to SQL standard they are equivalent.  In fact, the database engine's query optimizer is free to rewrite it to a form that is faster to run.

In most database engines I have encountered, they are completely equivalent.

However, if you are talking about OUTER JOIN's, then of course the left/right ordering is significant, not just for performance reasons.

Comment: I checked A INNER JOIN B AND B INNER JOIN A. There was vast difference in execution time. How can I justify that ? Also, the search criteria table is temporary table and A is in-memory table.

Comment: Can you post your query?  It shouldn't have a difference in SQL Server.  The query optimizer should take care of it.

Comment: Due to company SLA, I cant post any code. But I will try to post some small code.

Comment: Was the first one slow and the second one fast? Is the the same if you run the queries the other way around, i.e. test B INNER JOIN A and then A INNER JOIN B? (I'm just guessing that the server saw them as exactly equivalent queries and returned results from its cache the second time...)

Comment: HHHmmmm.... great point, @Matt Gibson!  The database may have cached all the pages from the first query.  So it is important to rerun several times to check.

Answer (score 0):

The `JOIN` order does not matter unless you explicitly provide `FORCE ORDER` in a hint.

The optimizer will choose the order it considers the most appropriate.

If you are asking about the join order in the actual plan, then yes, the join order definitely matters for nested loops or hash joins.

In case of a nested loop, the innermost table should be the larger one and the outermost should be the smaller one.

In case of a hash join, the probed table should be the larger one and the hashed one should be the smaller one.